# The preposition to use after the verb "to turn"

Tags: prepositional-verbs

I couldn't found the directions of using the proper prepositions with the verb **to turn**.

What is the right way of usage: *to turn to*, *to turn into* or *to turn* without any preposition? 
Especially in the context of colors changing.

> The red color turns ... pink when adding the white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*to turn into/to*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn) as both are valid because the color changes into or becomes (read the definition).

That said,

> The red color *turns into/to* pink when white is added

If I believe my sense, without any preposition also it'll look *okay.*

> The *red color turns pink* when white is added.

At least, there is no ambiguity.

From a Chemistry research paper, I found:

> Above pH 8.2, *phenol red turns a bright pink (fuchsia) color.*